# how to sort posts with average rating in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

i am using willvincent rateable package for rating the posts, it works fine and everypost has his rating in ratings table with each user_id,
so i am working on task where i want to sort posts with their average rating,

i build the raw sql which works well on phpmyadmin

```
SELECT *, AVG(ratings.rating) as average_rating
FROM posts
JOIN ratings ON ratings.rateable_id = posts.id
WHERE posts.user_id='2'
GROUP BY ratings.rateable_id
ORDER BY average_rating desc
```

but i want to convert it into laravel eloquent builder form, i achieve this till now

```
$postList->leftJoin('ratings', 'ratings.rateable_id', '=', 'posts.id')
            ->select(array('posts.*',
                DB::raw('AVG(rating) as ratings_average')   
                ))
            ->groupBy('posts.id')
            ->where('is_deleted','0')   
            ->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

where $postList has all posts with user_id but not giving all data from posts table online id with avg rating, please help

Answer (score 1):

When faced with trying to convert a SQL query to laravel's Query Builder, always check what `->toSql()` returns. You can do it by just using `dd` or `dump` (`dd($postList->.....->orderBy(...)->toSql())`) in your controller or in the console.

[image: Query in tinker returns the same SQL from the question]

```php
DB::connection('mysql')
  ->table('posts')
  ->selectRaw('*, avg(ratings.rating) as average_rating')
  ->join('ratings', 'ratings.rateable_id', 'posts.id')
  ->where('posts.user_id', '2')
  ->orderBy('ratings.rateable_id')
  ->orderByDesc('average_rating')
  ->get()
```

or, using the model.

```php
Posts::query()
  ->selectRaw('*, avg(ratings.rating) as average_rating')
  ->join('ratings', 'ratings.rateable_id', 'posts.id')
  ->where('posts.user_id', '2')
  ->orderBy('ratings.rateable_id')
  ->orderByDesc('average_rating')
  ->get()
```